# Unable to locate element for Linkedlin website under "Apply" button

Tags: xpath, dynamic

I created my own customized xpath for the following steps to LinkedIn:

1. www.linkedin.com - Launch the URL
2. Sign in
3. View Profile
4. Click on Jobs
5. Type in QA Lead
6. Click on Date Posted
7. Select within 24hrs
8. Click on Apply <------ Here where I am not able to click on this button.

Xpath:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("button[@class='facet-collection-list__cancel-button mr2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view']//span[text()='Cancel']/parent::button/following-sibling::button//span[@class='artdeco-button__text']")).click();

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU40o.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the expanded section first, then some unique attribute of the button, example:

Xpath: `//form[@aria-expanded='true']//button[@data-control-name='filter_pill_apply']`

css: `form[aria-expanded=true] button[class*=apply]`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I modified the xpath accordingly and it worked:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-control-name='filter_pill_cancel' and @class='facet-collection-list__cancel-button mr2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view']//span[@class='artdeco-button__text' and text()='Cancel']/parent::button/following-sibling::button//span[text()='Apply']")).click();